# Setting char* to NULL segfault

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault

In the function last_letter()
The line c = NULL will cause this program to segfault at while (*c)
Commenting it out will not. What's the reason? Setting char pointer to NULL and reassigning something to it? I thought setting pointers to NULL and reassigning them to something else was acceptable?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char s1[] = "abcdefg";
char s2[] = "xyz";
char* c;

void last_letter(char* a, int i) {
  printf("last_letter ( a is %s and i is %d)\n", a, i);
  sleep(i);
  c = NULL;   // comment out, what is different?
  sleep(i);
  c = a;
  sleep(i);
  while (*c) {
    c++;
  }
  printf("%c\n", *(c-1));
  return;
}


// This function will run concurrently.

void* aa(void *ptr) {
  last_letter(s2, 2);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t t1;
  int iret1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, aa, NULL);
  if (iret1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot create thread, rc=%d\n", iret1);
  }
  last_letter(s1, 5);
  sleep(10);
  printf("Ended nicely this time\n");
  return 0; //never reached when c = NULL is not commented out.
}
```

Comment: If you set `c` to NULL then the *other thread* might try to use `*c` while `c` is NULL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your variable `c` is global and so shared by all threads. Its used in `last_letter` which has the possibility of being called in both the main and the new thread at the same time. As it cannot be known the order in which each thread will execute `last_letter`, both may be interleaving changes to `c`. So one thread could set it to NULL when the other is expecting it to be a valid value.

One very simple way to very likely stop the crash  is to swap the order of the sleep and the call to `last_letter` in the main thread

```
sleep(10);
last_letter(s1, 5);
```

This buys `t1` 10 seconds to finish, which hopefully is enough. A better way to do it is to join `t1` before calling `last_letter` in the main thread. Yet a better way to do it is to move `c` inside `last_letter`, therefore each thread has a unique version of `c`and will not tread on the toes of the other threads. If `c` had to be shared, you would need to protect it with a mutex.

This way you needn't hold up main executing `last_letter` while `t1` also executes it. Since main and `t1` are operating on distinct data and also don't mutate that data, it's safe.

You would still want to call `join` on `t1` though, otherwise there is the possibility that the main might complete and exit before `t1` completes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

char s1[] = "abcdefg";
char s2[] = "xyz";

void last_letter(char* a, int i) {

  char* c;
  printf("last_letter ( a is %s and i is %d)\n", a, i);
  sleep(i);
  c = NULL; // pointless but if you must
  sleep(i);
  c = a;
  sleep(i);
  while (*c) {
    c++;
  }
  printf("%c\n", *(c-1));
}

// This function will run concurrently.
void* aa(void *ptr) {
  last_letter(s2, 2);
  return NULL;
}

int main() {
  pthread_t t1;

  int iret1 = pthread_create(&t1, NULL, aa, NULL);
  if (iret1) {
    fprintf(stderr,"Cannot create thread, rc=%d\n", iret1);
    return 0;
  }  

  last_letter(s1, 5);
  pthread_join(t1, NULL); // should check return value in production code

  printf("Ended nicely this time\n");
  return 0; //never reached when c = NULL is not commented out.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First, this is a classic race condition. This program depends on the order that aa() is called.

The last argument to **pthread_create()** is the argument. From the manpage:

```
int pthread_create(pthread_t *thread, const pthread_attr_t *attr,
                   void *(*start_routine) (void *), void *arg);
```

So when aa() is called via the pthread mechanism, the *a* argument is NULL, since **pthread_create()** is called with a NULL arg.

Then this loop dereferences a NULL pointer, causing a crash:

```
c = a;
sleep(i);
while (*c) {
    c++;
}
```

so give **pthread_create()** a non-NULL argument and you're on a better track.